# Make a data field in MySQL database update automatically each day or week?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a field in a MySQL database which i want to add a certain number each day or week whichever is easier to achieve. For example i have a field with the number 2000 in it and everyday or week i want to add 200 to that number.

Is this possible and if so how can i achieve it?

Comment: Use the MySQL [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html)

Comment: @MikeW if I am not mistaken u need privileges to use MySQL Event Scheduler, Danbyization is it a shared hosting or your own server/VPS ?

Comment: @Prix You need privileges for everything in MySQL.

Comment: Millions of ways to achieve it, it all depends on what privileges you have on that server. In the worst case you can write a web script, that makes these modifications to your DB and schedule calling this script on any other machine (via wget, curl or whatever), where you have enough privileges.

Comment: @MikeW yes you do however Event's privileges are not common on shared hosting for example. So I would not expect anyone with a shared hosting to be able to use it.

Comment: In addition to @DavidJashi comment you can also use cronjob which is available on most shared hosting if you don't have your own VPS/server, you can also use Google schedule tasks to trigger a page from your website that would update it, etc.

Comment: @Prix Since the OP hasn't made any comment we don't know that he's using shared hosting, or that he doesn't have the required privilege

Comment: @MikeW yes we don't that's why I wanted to make it clear that for MySQL Event Scheduler he needs specific privileges which in **some cases are not available**.

Comment: @Prix I'm using my friends server so i will have to check with him whether i have privileges for event scheduler or not.

Comment: May I ask you why you want to do this? Unconditionnally incrementing a value on a regular basis looks like you are tring to implement a timer. If so, there are probably other (better?) approaches.

Comment: @RandomSeed I'm trying to make a banking database for a virtual company and i want to add on the running costs of the company e.g. £2,00 a day.

Comment: I see, then your use case does make sense, of course. This is, however, something I would normally handle at the application layer in a real situation.

Comment: Ah right well this isnt for a real company this is just me messing about practising my skills lol

Answer (score 0):

Just write a SQL function which will return the field times number of week for example.

I do not post a complete function because the question is not that clear about what you expected to return